# Программа обработки файла типа запись,c++

Tags: c++

Пожалуйста, помогите новичку понять в чем могут быть ошибки. Долго не могу разобраться.

> ```
> Ошибка C2360 пропуск инициализации "middle" из-за метки "case"
> Ошибка C2143 синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "константа"
> Ошибка C2017 недопустимая escape-последовательность
> Ошибка (активно) E0007 нераспознанная лексема
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct student {
    int ID;
    string name;
    int year;
    int gnum;
    struct marks {
        int phys, math, inf, chem;
    }mark;
    double sb;
}student;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");


start: cout << "\n\t1 - Создание\n\t2 - Просмотр\n\t3 - Коррекция\n\t4 - Решение индивидуального задания\n\t5";

    ifstream fin("students.txt", ios_base::in); 
    ofstream fout("students.txt", ios::app); 

    int key;
    string a;
    int ID, scale, year;
    char name;
    cin >> key;
    switch (key) {
    case 1:
        cout << "\n\tВведите фамилия и инициалы: ";
        cin.get();
        getline(cin, student.name);
        cout << "\n\tВведите год рождения: ";
        cin >> student.year;
        cout << "\n\tВведите номер группы: ";
        cin >> student.gnum;
        cout << "\n\tОценка по физике: ";
        cin >> student.mark.phys;
        cout << "\n\tОценка по математике: ";
        cin >> student.mark.math;
        cout << "\n\tОценка по информатике: ";
        cin >> student.mark.inf;
        cout << "\n\tОценка по химии: ";
        cin >> student.mark.chem;


        int middle = student.mark.phys + student.mark.math + student.mark.inf + student.mark.chem\4;
        cout << middle;

        student.sb = (student.mark.phys + student.mark.math + student.mark.inf + student.mark.chem) / 4;

        fout <<" \n" << student.ID <<" "<< student.name << "\t" << student.year << "\t" << student.gnum << "\t" << student.mark.phys << "\t" << student.mark.math << "\t" << student.mark.inf << "\t" << student.mark.chem << "\t" << student.sb <<"\n";
        goto start;
        break;
    case 2:                    
        if (fin.is_open()) {     
            while (fin >> student.ID) {
                fin >> student.name >> student.year >> student.gnum >> student.mark.phys >> student.mark.math >> student.mark.inf >> student.mark.chem >> student.sb;

                cout << student.name << "\t" << student.year << "\t" << student.gnum << "\t" << student.mark.phys << "\t" << student.mark.math << "\t" << student.mark.inf << "\t" << student.mark.chem << "\t" << student.sb<<"\n";
            }
        }

        break;

    case 5:
        break;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А строки, на которых обнаружены ошибки, известны? Если да, пометьте их как-то пожалуйста. Легче будет разобраться

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с простейшего. Ну кто же так делит?! `\4`? Делить надо так, как двумя строками ниже - `/4`.

Далее - внутри `case`ничего просто так инициализировать нельзя. В общем случае представьте сложный класс, который инициализируется в `case 1`, и виден в `case 2` - и что будет, если вы попадаете прямо в `case 2`? Минуя `case 1` и инициализацию? С чем работать придется?...

Варианты - вынесите объявление `middle` за пределы `switch` или поместите тело `case 1` в фигурные скобки...

Впрочем, у вас эта переменная используется только для вывода, так что я бы написал

```
cout <<  student.mark.phys + student.mark.math + student.mark.inf + student.mark.chem/4;
```

и не мучился... :)

P.S. Вот с первой ошибкой просто стыдно, да? Как тому студенту-медику. Запамятовал, кто из великих медиков, как-то на практических занятиях сказал, мол, главные качества врача - внимательность и отсутствие брезгливости. Вот ведь как древние врачи проводили анализ мочи на сахар? При этом он опустил палец в баночку с мочой, вынул и облизал, и предложил повторить.
Студенты мялись, но наконец, нашелся один, повторивший подвиг профессора.
- Браво, коллега! Браво! Одно свойство врача у вас уже есть - отсутствие брезгливости. Осталась внимательность - вы не обратили внимания, что я опустил в мочу средний палец, а облизал указательный?...

Простите уж, но когда компилятор указывает на такие простые ошибки... словом, внимательность нужна не только медикам...